# Why is Fortify flagging this as an unreleased resource?

Tags: java, security, synchronization, locking, fortify

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
    final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    Object read() {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        Object result;
        try {
            result = getResource();
        } finally {
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Fortify flags the method `read` with `Unreleased Resource: Synchronization`, claiming that the lock is obtained and then the method is simply exited right after without releasing the lock.

My hunch is that, since the `lock` field is of the interface type `ReadWriteLock`, Fortify can't tell that `lock.readLock()` is guaranteed to return the same `Lock` object for both calls. So, Fortify sees that the `Lock` we locked on isn't stored in a local variable, and it thinks that the `Lock` is therefore lost and leaked. Is this correct?

Comment: That's my guess. Any reason not to save it in a variable?

Comment: Not that I can see. I'm going to store the lock in a final local variable and see if that resolves it after our next scan.

Comment: Definitely make sure to self-answer if that fixes it. (And why aren't `Lock`s `AutoCloseable`?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hunch was correct. Fortify couldn't tell that `lock.readLock()` returned the same `Lock` object for both calls, and storing the lock in a `final` local variable solved the issue.